# Prevent page being post back if javascript validations fails

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation

I've following asp **text box**:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPasswrod" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

below this text box I've **error message label**, which is **initially hidden** until the **js validation** of the text box **fails**:

```
<label id="errorMsg" for="pwd" style="display:none">error</label >
```

Following is the **js** for textbox **validation**:

```
function validation() 
{
  var pwd = document.getElementById("txtPasswrod").value;
  if (pwd == null || pwd == "") 
  {
    document.getElementById("error").style.display = 'block';
    return false;
  }
}
```

Following is the **asp button**, whose **OnClientClick** event I am calling **validation()** function:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
     onclick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="validation()"/>
```

The validation is working **all fine**, but the problem is that when **text box** is **empty** and my **validation fails** the **js** should **prevent page from being post back**, but the **js allowing the page being post back** and my validation jst becoming **useless**.

Please tell me how to **prevent page postback on failing the js validation**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a slight change in your JS script. You need to add `.ClientID` as the control you are specifying is a server control. Or if you are on .net 4.0 , you can use `ClientIDMode= "Static"` to access the control as you are using in your code.

```
function validation() {
                var pwd = document.getElementById('<%=txtPasswrod.ClientID').value;
                if (pwd == null || pwd == "") 
                {
                    document.getElementById("errorMsg").style.display = 'block';
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Now call the validation method something like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
     onclick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="return validation();"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Modify `validation()` to `return validation()`, This will stop page to post if `function` returns `false`.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
     onclick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="return validation();"/>
```

Comment: your answer is write but another thing i added is: <%=txtCustOldPwd.ClientID%> as told by amit... thanx for your helps.